# Unknown spacecraft reference. "Wang's vehicle"

Tags: history, launch-vehicle, hllv

I've got a mystery for you today:

In Dan Sharp's book, "British Secret Projects - 5 - Britain's Space Shuttle" ISBN:,9781910809020 MUSTARD (Multi Unit Space Transport And Reuse Device) is compared with many other contemporary paper and real rockets.

One of these is listed as being ~10,200M GBP development cost, and ~10^6.8 LB when manufactured, making it more massive than the largest ROMBUS design, and similar to about ~1.4 Saturn V's.

I'd like to include a reference photo, but I fear it is under copyright.
If you can find a source, here's the year: 1964, and it's a BAC chart of American vs. European projects.

[image]

WHAT IS THIS "WANG'S VEHICLE"?
I can find no reference to it anywhere other than this photo, so it may be an earlier abandoned project.
I know this may be too vague, but hopefully something turns up.

Comment: What does *10^6.8 LB*? Is it 0.8 million lb mass or 6.31 million lb mass (where 10^0.8 = 6.31)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that reproducing the photo here for the purpose of this question constitutes "fair use". Without it, I doubt you get any meaningful answer unless someone happens to have the book.

Comment: @ludo, will do.

Comment: Might have been something proposed by Wang Xjii who was prominent in the Chinese space program https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Xiji

Comment: The timeline is problematic, the only big Wang I can think of, as above, was busy with PRC's first sounding rocket at the time, fuelled by a bicycle pump. Must be another Wang...

Comment: As far as I can tell Wang Xjii was already talking up what eventually became the Long March rockets in the early 60s, even if it was just a vague concept, so I think it still fits in the timeline. I have to assume "Wang's Vehicle" was his proposed final form of the Long March series, with a vaguely estimated cost and mass.

Comment: There is no need to close it. Sometimes questions get answered months or years later.

Comment: Wonder if it was a massive hypersonic waverider that was popular around that time?

Comment: Probably not, I think given Wang's other designs, it's probably a SHLV, like the nexus.

Comment: Fair enough. Thats quite a mystery..

Comment: I mean tbh what do I know.
Just a hunch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit more information can be found on page 111 of the same book. "possibly the largest and most costly space vehicle ever designed - a design produced by H.E. Wang of the California-based Aerospace Corporation and known to the British as 'Wang's Vehicle'".

The [Aerospace Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Aerospace_Corporation) is an American nonprofit corporation that operates a federally funded research and development center (FFRDC) in El Segundo, California.
Its goal is "to serve the Air Force in the scientific and technical planning and management of missile-space programs."

Comment: Whoever named that operation "The Aerospace Corporation" clearly wasn't planning ahead for Google searches.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Curious how Musk's latest business is doing, I googled "What is the value of X?" with similar results.

Comment: @uhoh Haha. I guess we'll get XpaceX and Xesla next!

Comment: Since Aerospace Corp. still exists and has a [contact page](https://aerospace.org/contact-us), I sent them an email. Let's see what comes from that.

Comment: From the timeline i guessed it was Dyna-soar X-20 related, that or MOL, and AC was USAF specific at that time. Wangs papers date from that decade, coinciding with a lot of fanciful large concepts, but nothing that really matches that 1964 chart.

Comment: The Aerospace Corporation does (or did, when I was there) work for NASA JSC too. When I worked in SSP systems engineering during the recovery from the STS-107 failure, they were in a lot of meetings I went to.

Comment: Yes, I was only referring to the early AC period that was USAF specific, after MOL it seemed they opened up to working with NASA, as the USAF manned space flight efforts had dried up.

Comment: I got an answer already: no references to “Wang’s vehicle” in any of their digital or print collections. Dr. H.E. Wang did work on MOL but *not* on DynaSoar. All of his MOL work is labelled for internal use only, anything that is public should be on DTIC.

Comment: DTIC only has one paper by him, title "Variable-Lift Re-Entry at Superorbital and Orbital Speeds", which is a mathematical treatise that has no vehicle designs.

Answer (score 0):

Partial or not really an answer:

(Edit update, as per Ludo's comment, its not X-20)

TL;DR:

Could it have been a future enlarged spaceplane or booster related to Dyna-soar?

Or a future enlarged version of MOL?

Note:

The chart is from 1964, Dyna-soar was already cancelled, MOL had been announced the previous year. There could already have been enlarged projections developed for beyond the X-20 program, and MOL was going to be a very large and expensive space station.

Probably doesn't fit but...

in the 1960's Wang was looking at aerodynamics of large payload fairings on launch vehicles, the type that would have carried the X-20 Dyna-soar, which was, at the time, considered pretty expensive - the launch vehicle settled upon was Titan IIIC (though the Saturn would have able to launch it as well, that was under NASA control, not the Air Force).

Examples of large vehicles being drawn up throughout the period:

https://media.defense.gov/2021/Apr/06/2002615086/-1/-1/0/RECOVERABLE%20BOOSTERS.PDF

With the switch to MOL he would still have been looking at enlarged fairings on future launch vehicles.

He also had a paper on variable re-entry at orbital and super orbital speeds in 1962. With the Dyna-soar travelling at high Mach, those studies might be related.

Of course Dyna-soar was cancelled in 1963, and MOL, the military space station, was next on the development list, which was also subsequently cancelled in 1969, and was considered even more expensive than the X-20 had been (US$1.5bn).

Wangs papers could also be related to MOL as the launch fairing research is from 1967, long after X-20 was cancelled but MOL astronauts were being selected and announced by this time.

By 1969 future MOLs were envisioned - crews of 12 and 40 envisaged in orbiting command and control posts with shuttles replenishing them. MOL's roadmap continued into 1980, and included the following concepts:

40 man crew:

[image]

Aerospace Corporation still exists and is a federally funded research and development institution, and at the time Wang was working, its primary focus was in assisting the US Air Force with scientific, technical planning, and management of its ballistic-missile and space programs, which is where the X-20 and later MOL come in.

By the 1970s Aerospace Corporation was very much involved with NASA and the STS program and no longer solely associated with the USAF.

So with both X-20 and MOL being the very expensive programs they were, and being researched and developed during that decade, makes them potential vehicles.

Links:

Dyna-soar information:

https://documents.theblackvault.com/documents/dynasoar/AFD-080408-031.pdf

https://www.thespacereview.com/article/2866/1

> The last spacemen: MOL and what might have been

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manned_Orbiting_Laboratory

> MOL program managers hoped to build larger, permanent facilities. A planning document depicted 12-man and 40-man stations, both with self-defense capability.

https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/102893058

> A study of the characteristics of transonic buffet pressures on a large hammerhead configuration by H.E. Wang.

https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/trecms/pdf/AD0278161.pdf

> VARIABLE-LIFT RE-ENTRY AT SUPERORBITAL AND ORBITAL SPEEDS H.E. Wang

https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/epdf/10.2514/3.3142

> Motion of re-entry vehicles during constant- altitude glide by H. E. WANG

Lifting Entry Concepts

Motion of re-entry vehicles during constant-altitude glide (1965)

Variable lift re-entry at super-orbital and orbital speeds (1963)

Entry vehicle design study Document ID 19640004844

On Boundary Layers Associated with Oscillating Streams 1961

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00411895#auth-H__E_-Wang-Aff1

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19670002370/downloads/19670002370.pdf

A VARIABLE-LIFT PROGRAM FOR SATELLITE RE-ENTRY 1961

APPROXIMATE SOLUTIONS OF THE LATERAL MOTION OF RE-ENTRY VEHICLES DURING CONSTANT ALTITUDE GLIDE 1963

Comment: Not really an answer, in light of Ludo's efforts, so just undeleted for the papers i found cited but mostly unavailable. A lot of them seem hypersonic related, hence my thought of x-20. But future enlarged MOL might fit the large size and expenditure expected for an orbital station. Perhaps.

Comment: The graph shows that 'Wang's vehicle' has an _empty_ weight of 7 million pounds, that's close to a fully-fueled Saturn V.

Comment: I know, i ran out of ideas, and without much further info, i sort of gave up. What is available is very much hypersonic...which made me trawl through a lot of the concepts of the period. As pointed out, his papers are mathematical and nothing points to vehicle concepts specifically.